# How can I centre the whole window in Python?

Tags: python, tkinter, layout

I've created two windows with the same exact code. 
In the first window, the text is centred however in the second its not.
I would appreciate your help!
Thanks

```
    def order_page(self):
        newwindow = Tk()
        newwindow.title("Take an Order")
        newwindow.geometry('1920x1080')
        newheader = Label(newwindow,
            text="Hello",
            fg="Black",
            bg="Bisque",
            pady=5,
            font="Verdana 10 bold italic",
            width=100,
            height=3)
        newheader.grid()
        newwindow.mainloop()
```

Comment: Use `newheader.pack()` instead, `.pack()` centers by default.

Comment: For grid you simply define the column weight.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using grid and you want to center a widget you need to define the weight of the area you want to center.

Here is an example:

```
from tkinter import *


newwindow = Tk()
newwindow.title("Take an Order")
newwindow.geometry('1920x1080')
# column configure is used to define the weight of a specific column.
newwindow.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
# if you want to also want the row to expand then use rowconfigure()
# newwindow.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)

newheader = Label(newwindow, text="Hello", fg="Black", bg="Bisque", font="Verdana 10 bold italic", width=100, height=3)
newheader.grid(row=0, column=0, pady=5)

newwindow.mainloop()
```

Results:

[image]

With `rowconfigure(0, weight=1)`:

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: @MihaiRadoi Glad to help. If my answer solved your problem please select the check mark next to the answer to let everyone know the issue solved.